# Who is ISIS/ISIL, Really?

Tags: military, civil-war

For the past 6 months or so (probably longer), I've heard a lot about ISIS, and I know that they are involved in military actions in Syria, but I am still confused as to what their true purpose is. If possible, I would like to know:
1. How ISIS formed
2. Why they are involved in the Syrian Civil War
3. Why they are recruiting American teenagers
4. What is their true "goal" (as in, why did they form in the first place)

If anyone can answer even one of these questions, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The Atlantic has a [great article on ISIS](http://www.theatlantic.com/features/archive/2015/02/what-isis-really-wants/384980/) that answers most of your question. It is called "What ISIS Really Wants."

Comment: This probably belongs on the Politics stack. Only #1 refers to an event that has finished occurring.

Comment: @twosheds thank you, I wanted to link to the same article, you spared me the effort!

Comment: question is either OP or trivial to answer using wikipedia

Comment: Does this really belong to History? Probably not yet. (To my regrett)

Comment: @TylerDurden definitely not trivial. But not history either.

Comment: I think it should be migrated to Politics.SE